# Jquery cannot paginate conflict

Tags: jquery

I have 7 results paginated with jquery.

I also have checkbox form which filters the results normally.

The problem is that when I filter the results, pagination does not work normally after that.

Probably the conflict is because both filter and pagination codes use show() hide() methods.

Could you please help me to solve the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/EducateYourself/ev9eze33/5/

```
function update() {
    $('.resultblock').hide();
    if (categories.length > 0) {
        $('.resultblock').hide();
        for (i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            $('.resultblock[data-tag*="'+categories[i]+'"]').show();
        } 
    }
    $('.resultblock:lt('+currentFirstElement+')').hide();
    $('.resultblock:gt('+(currentFirstElement+numberPerPage-1)+')').hide();
    $('#count').html('Count: '+$(".resultblock:visible").length);
    $('#totalcount').html('Total Count: '+$(".resultblock").length);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite complicated, you can make your life easier by doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var categories = [];
    var currentFirstElement = 0;
    var numberPerPage = 3;
    update();

    $(".category").click(function(e) {
        if (this.checked)
            categories.push(this.value);
        else
            categories.splice(categories.indexOf(this.value), 1);
        update();
    });

    $(".pageButton").click(function() {
        currentFirstElement = Number(this.text)*numberPerPage-numberPerPage;
        $('#page').html('Page #'+this.text);
        update();
    });

    function update() {
        $('.resultblock').hide();
        if (categories.length > 0) {
            $('.resultblock').hide();
            for (i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
                $('.resultblock[data-tag*="'+categories[i]+'"]').show();
            } 
        }
        $('.resultblock:lt('+currentFirstElement+')').hide();
        $('.resultblock:gt('+(currentFirstElement+numberPerPage-1)+')').hide();
        $('#count').html('Count: '+$(".resultblock:visible").length);
        $('#totalcount').html('Total Count: '+$(".resultblock").length);
    };
});
```

This works as expected.

## [> DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6z4z6jj/)

Comment: To remove the page-links upon filtering for the different categories, consider checking whether each page contains at least one of the selected categories and `.hide()` the page if this is not the case. This can be achieved using a simple `for loop`.

Comment: @EducateYourself I can take a look tomorrow. Just like I did, you can add the checked boxes to an array and then check whether this array contains any elements. If not, you change the class back.